# CodeIgniter HTTP Error 500

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

When I try to access the website I get this error:

> HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request

even after removing the htaccess file completely the website is still not working. NOTE: on localhost it's working fine.

## Edit after comments:

I think I wasn't clear enough here's my problem in details:
I have a website written with PHP5 no framework or cms or anything and it work fine.
Then I start the admin section so I used CodeIgniter and rewrite the site.
Now I almost done with the programming so I uploaded a test version to the server **in a subfolder** to test it but the 500 error mentioned above appeared, my first thoughts were that it's a htaccess file problem so I try other htaccess files and finally removed it from the server, but the problem still there.
Now the only difference between my local server and the remote server is that locally i'm running PHP 5.3.5 and remotely it's PHP 5.2.14.
That's all the information that I can think of now.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: "500" means "The developer / admin / etc should look in the server logs to find the error message".

Comment: i don't have access to the server only ftp access.

Comment: If the logs are not available to you (and only having ftp access (horrible though that is) doesn't mean they aren't), then you are screwed. Get hosting that isn't appallingly awful.

Comment: With FTP you can normally also get to the logs directory; it's one up from the public_html (on most machines)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likey have a missing PHP/Apache module hence the 500 error.

1: Check your logs within the root and the dir your running script in, else the directory above root/logs.

2: Create a file called phpinfo.php, in it put:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

and run it.

3: Then compare the list of installed extensions shown in the output with the list of installed modules you have locally.

If your using WAMP, you click the tray icon, goto PHP->extentions and you can see all that are installed. Same for Apache.

boff

additionally:

A good start would to to make sure CURL and MBSTRING is on, however I don't use CAKE PHP....

Comment: No idea why you assume it to be a module. 500 are also generated by requiring or including a non-existing file, by rewrite rules in htaccess files or when you've disabled error_reporting and display_errors..

Comment: @Luceos The most non-obvious 500 errors are normally caused by missing modules/extensions in my experience, and my experience of PHP spans back to the early 1940's where me and Ban Ki-Moon used to write PHP in the war.

Comment: Well, its 2012 now. Welcome to the new era.

Comment: Who asked you @itachi? You pipe up again and me and Ban Ki are coming round there.

Comment: I guess you didn't get the point. 1. He mentioned he doesn't have access to the root. If he doesn't, he can't check logs. Plz read comments before answering. 2. If the server is returning 500 error, how he suppose to run phpinfo check? 3. If step 2 isn't possible, how can he do step 3?

Comment: Well he's not specifying what code he's using so you can't assume what will and won't. If he clearly stated that the server will not serve any page under any circumstance then your point would be valid, however he hasn't, but rather he's implied he's using some CAKE PHP application he has created that works locally but not online. This suggests to me there's something specific in his code that is incompatible with his live server, but that regular code will work. If he strips his code down to just php info, then it will work, else the server is not set up by host.

Comment: @itachi from above... so in short, the problem is most likely his code and phpinfo will work fine, else there's little he can do about it as the host hasn't set up the server correctly. So perhaps it was you who missed the point?

Comment: it was the web-security2 module that is messing from the local machine thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I got same problem and added this line on top

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```